# How can I create a custom calendar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a custom calendar, like this, I am stucked in it from 2 days i have used almost all packges but did not done like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SzSM.png

Answer (score 0):

Hello i used this [flutter_clean_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_clean_calendar) package. Customized for my needs you can try this.

this is how i customize [flutter_clean_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_clean_calendar) its looks like yours but in this one appointments shown by selected date. for example if you select december 20 you see december 20 appointments. i think yours somelike 2 seperate widget, on the top horizontal calendar, bottom is scrollable listview.

[image]